# Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:14 cannot recognize input near 'select' '*' 'from' in join source

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jdbc, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have set of Scala where i'm trying to load data into hive table using spark while connect hive table I'm experiencing below error

Code

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[2]").appName("interfacing spark sql to hive metastore without configuration file")
      .config("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir", "C:\\xxxx\\xxxx\\xxxx\\")
      .enableHiveSupport() // don't forget to enable hive support
      .getOrCreate()

    val sc = spark.sparkContext
    val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext
    val driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"

    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:\\xxxx\\xxxx\\xxxx\\xxxx\\xxxx\\security\\jssecacerts")
    System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.debug","true")
    System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf",new File("C:\\xxxx\\xxxx\\krb5.conf").getAbsolutePath)
    System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly", "false")
    System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", new File("C:\\xxxx\\xxxx\\jaas.conf").getAbsolutePath)
    val hiveurl="jdbc:hive2://xxxxx.octorp.com:10000/devl_dkp;user=pcpdosr;password=Kopdevp1;ssl=true;AuthMech=3"
    //;mapred.job.queue.name=dkl"
    val connectionProperties = new java.util.Properties()

    sc.setLocalProperty("spark.scheduler.pool", "dkl")
    val hiveQuery = "select * from devl_dkp.employee"

    val hiveResult = spark.read.option("driver",driverName).jdbc(hiveurl, hiveQuery, connectionProperties).collect()
```

Error

```
exception caught: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:14 cannot recognize input near 'select' '*' 'from' in join source
```

Any help will be appreciated thanks

Comment: _"Hive support"_ in Spark means that **you don't use JDBC** to read/write into Hive tables. RTFM.

Comment: May i know the reason why didn't I use JDBC to read/write into Hive table?

Comment: _"you don't use"_ is imperative -- meaning "you should not use", "you are not supposed to use", "it will not work if you try". So you did not read the Spark documentation, you tried to access Hive via JDBC, it did not work. That's a good reason why.